# Is there a difference between a Null data.table and an empty data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

Small example:

```
library(data.table)
l <- list(data.table(a=c("a", "b", "c"), b=c(1, 2, 3)),
          data.table(),
          data.table(d=c("x", "y", "z"), e=c(9, 8, 7))
     )    

> l
[[1]]
   a b
1: a 1
2: b 2
3: c 3

[[2]]
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

[[3]]
   d e
1: x 9
2: y 8
3: z 7
```

In production, I have this list:

```
[[3]]
                 rn blogs news twitter count qmle
1: almost feel like     1    1       1     3  0.5

[[4]]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: rn,blogs,news,twitter,count
```

So is `l[[2]]` the same like `[[3]]` in production?

Also, I want to compress the list, such that only data.tables remain which are not NULL or empty, respectively. How do I do that?

I tried to use `Filter`, but the empty data.tables remain in the list.

```
> Filter(length, x[386:390])
[[1]]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: rn,blogs,news,twitter,count

[[2]]
                       rn blogs news twitter count       qmle
1:       almost every day    12    2       1    15 0.25423729
2: almost everything else     2    2       1     5 0.08474576

[[3]]
                       rn blogs news twitter count qmle
1: almost everything else     2    2       1     5  0.5

[[4]]
                 rn blogs news twitter count qmle
1: almost feel like     1    1       1     3  0.5

[[5]]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: rn,blogs,news,twitter,count
```

Comment: Try `Filter(nrow, l)`

Comment: See adjusted post with example.

Comment: I changed `length` to `nrow`.  It should work now

Comment: Your title is question 2.5 in the FAQ, more or less: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf

Comment: true. going in that direction and good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the list elements with `Filter` and use `nrow`.  This should work for both `NULL` as well as `empty` data.table.  In the first case, I suggested `length`, but if we look at the `str(l[[4]])`, it still has five columns with 0 rows.  So, `length` will give the `ncol` ie. 5 and so it will be also included when we use `length` in the `Filter`.  Whereas, `nrow` in NULL and `empty` are `0`.  Within the `Filter`, 0 will be coerced to 'FALSE' and everything else to 'TRUE'.

```
 Filter(nrow, l)
 #[[1]]
 #   a b
 #1: a 1
 #2: b 2
 #3: c 3

 #[[2]]
 #   d e
 #1: x 9
 #2: y 8
 #3: z 7
```

#### data

```
 l[[4]] <- as.data.table(matrix(, ncol=5, nrow=0))
```

Comment: @TMOTTM still waiting for accept 3 years later ... along with most of your other questions